# Purchasing a good gaming laptop

Tags: laptop, performance, gaming, help

I just purchased my 3rd gaming laptop for when I travel for work. I’m having second thoughts. Can anyone help me with my decision.

Comment: Yeah.  Try get a refund for it and find a responsible person (parent or lawyer) to act as your financial guardian.    From the way your question is written - ie no information which would help us help you make an informed decision - and without having bothered to familiarize yourself with how this site works - your brain needs to develop further before you can trust it with monetary decisions.